# Map columns' values to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataset with some customer information, with one column containing device codes (identifying the device used). I need to translate this codes into actual model names. 
I also have a second table with a column holding device codes (same as the first table) and another column holding the corresponding model names. 
I know it may seem trivial, I have managed to translate codes into models by using a for loop, .loc method and conditional substitution, but I'm looking for a more structured solution.

Here's an extract of the data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Device_code': ['SM-A520F','SM-A520F','iPhone9,3','LG-H860', 'WAS-LX1A', 'WAS-LX1A']
    }
)
```

```
transcription_table=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Device_code': ['SM-A520F','SM-A520X','iPhone9,3','LG-H860', 'WAS-LX1A', 'XT1662','iPhone11,2'],
        'models': ['Galaxy A5(2017)','Galaxy A5(2017)','iPhone 7','LG G5', 'P10 lite', 'Motorola Moto M','iPhone XS']
    }
)
```

Basically I need to obtain the explicit model of the device every time there's a match between the device_code column of the two tables, and overwrite the device_code of the first table (df) with the actual model name (or, it can be written on the same row into a newly created column, this is less of a problem).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your `transcription_table` into an actual mapping (aka a dictionary) and then use `Series.map`:

```
transcription_dict = dict(transcription_table.values)
df['models'] = df['Device_code'].map(transcription_dict)
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Device_code           models
0    SM-A520F  Galaxy A5(2017)
1    SM-A520F  Galaxy A5(2017)
2   iPhone9,3         iPhone 7
3     LG-H860            LG G5
4    WAS-LX1A         P10 lite
5    WAS-LX1A         P10 lite
```

Comment: Precisely what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just one solution:

```
# Dictionary that maps device codes to models
mapping = transcription_table.set_index('Device_code').to_dict()['models']

# Apply mapping to a new column in the dataframe
# If no match is found, None will be filled in
df['Model'] = df['Device_code'].apply(lambda x: mapping.get(x))
```